# Microsoft account security alert - Is this legit?

Tags: email-spoofing, microsoft

I've just received two emails in a row stating that "We detected something unusual about a recent sign-in for the Microsoft account" and "someone else might have accessed the Microsoft account..." (see image attached). Seems a little "phishy" to me considering it's a *gmail* account. Last time I checked gmail was owned by Google not Microsoft. But what's weird is when clicking on the recover account button it appears to lead to the real Microsoft website. Can someone please confirm if this is a scam?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is unknown to us if you have a Microsoft account. But it is pretty normal to have an email not managed/owned by Microsoft for your Microsoft account the same way as it is normal to have an email not managed/owned by Amazon for your Amazon account.

Answer (score 1):

I admit that it looks phishy but this, however, is *not* a scam : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/osecurity-oinfosafe/is-this-adress-a-valid-ms-one-or-a-fraud/de185bc8-e2aa-47ba-a526-28d80ad577b1

The fact that you used a GMail address to sign up for a Microsoft service is not abnormal at all (you can also have a Google account and use an @hotmail.com or @outlook.com address for that). It's just the e-mail address where they can contact you on (as they did now)

I would highly recommend

1. resetting your password asap
2. setting up an Authenticator app for multi-factor authentication

Comment: Alright in that case, why don't they even tell me what the email address is? I actually have two gmail accounts that begin with to...@gmail.com. And I'm not sure why I would even have a "Microsoft account", whatever that is for, as I use a Mac. Only thing I can think of is my xbox live account but that has a separate @live.com email address.

Answer (score -1):

**No it is almost certainly not legit!**   *(edit:* **Maybe!**)

The phrase

```
"*... accessed the Microsoft account to*****@gmail.com ..."
```

is a red flag. Microsoft would have no knowledge of someone accessing a gmail account.

Pay careful attention to the links and don't click on them. They likely don't resolve to where they say they do.

If you can examine the email headers, full reality can be determined.

**** Edit ****

**I stand corrected!** I read the message literally as the gmail account, since that's what it seems to say. Apparently Microsoft refers to microsoft accounts by external email names used to create them.

Given that, it could indeed be legit, but the way it's handled by Microsoft looks just like fraud.

Examine the raw message with headers to determine reality if possible.

**Either way, don't click on the links**. Manually enter the account recovery URL from another source.

Comment: This is wrong, because you can have a Microsoft account with any email address you want, not just one of theirs.

Comment: Manually entering that link would be...Problematic.  The only real steps that you need to take are to verify that the domain in the in link is legitimate, and then once you've done that and clicked the link, that the certificate is valid.